# Stream Audio (back ground music) for unreal engine 4

Tags: audio, game-engine, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

Is it possible to stream an audio (RESTApi ) in UE4 for a game, I checked the audio docs from UE4, seems like we need to drop audio files as an asset and load it accordingly, is there any possibility to stream audio from the server as a simple HTTP stream for a game in UE4
Any advice would be a great help.
(https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/WorkingWithMedia/Audio/index.html)

Comment: Does it need to stream from the server? That is doable but will come at a high cost in terms of bandwidth and break the reliability of things like character movement (if your project is a game that is). The general approach would be to have an audio asset exist on both and replicate down a reference to the correct asset.

Comment: Thanks, George. Yes, the requirement is to stream from the server. I need to do a feasibility check any reference link or classes to stream the audio would be great